# How can I plot a discrete dataset using Qwt/Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, plot, qwt

The [stem](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html)  command in MATLAB plots a discrete data sequence.

[image: stem]

Is there any equivalent class/method in [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) to achieve a similar output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393279/tutorial-on-graphs-plotting-qwt

Comment: that is a totally different question, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [QwtPlotHistogram](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_histogram.html) and/or [QwtPlotBarChart](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/6.1/class_qwt_plot_bar_chart.html). You probably have to subclass and reimplement the exact behavior you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It's too late for my answer. But for others who want to do the same, you can use a [QwtPlotCurve](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_curve.html#a15998aa80a11ba6ba80eebabaf773f70) and call `setStyle(QwtPlotCurve::Steps)` or `setStyle(QwtPlotCurve::Sticks)`.